Decomposing a general stopping time into stopping components
Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a discrete-time Markov chain taking values in a finite state space $S$, with transition matrix $P$. Let $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be the natural filtration and let $\tau \geq 1$ be a finite stopping time. Prove that, for any $x \in S$ and any function $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb R$, there are stopping times $(\tau_{x,y})_{y \in S}$ such that
$$ E_x [f(X_\tau)]   = \sum_{y\in S}P(x,y) E_y[f(X_{\tau_{x,y}})]$$
I would like to see the proof of this statement.
Context: This is a remark from the paper "The Optimal Stopping Rule for a Two-Person Markov Chain with Opposing Interests" - E. B. Frid, which I don't know how it is true. The author explained like in the picture below

There's a clear typo, it should reads "...$ \tau_{x,y} $ on the trajectory $xa_0a_1a_2...$ is equal to 0 if $a_0 \neq y$....". But even with this hint, I don't see why the equality holds and furthermore, I believe $\tau_{x,y}$ defined in the picture is not a stopping time (or Markov moment) because $\tau -1$ is not a stopping time!
The best of my knowledge is that if $\tau \geq 1$ is a first entrance time  of some fixed set then this is just the usual strong Markov property, which is well-known. But for the general $\tau \geq 1$ above, I just don't think it is true.

(The $y$ in Frid's notation is misleading.)
Instead, for a stopping time $\tau\ge 1$ and a state $x$, define $T_x(\omega):=\tau(x\omega)-1$. (Here, for a path $\omega=a_0a_1a_2\cdots$, the concatenation $x\omega$ denotes the path $xa_0a_1\cdots$. You can check that $T_x$ is a stopping time for each $x\in S$, and that $\tau(\omega) = 1+T_{X_0(\omega)}(\theta_1\omega)$, where $\theta_1$ applied to a path $a_0a_1a_2\cdots$ is the path $a_1a_2a_3\cdots$.
The formula in question results from the simple Markov property applied at time $t=1$, because  $X_\tau(\omega) = X_{T_{x}(\theta_1\omega)}(\theta_1\omega)$, in which $x:=X_0(\omega)$. Therefore
$$
\mathbf E_x[f(X_\tau)] = \sum_{y\in S} \mathbf P_x[X_1=y]\cdot\mathbf E_y[f(X_{T_x})].
$$

Let's say $X_n(\omega) = \omega_n$ then $X_\tau(\omega) = \omega_{1 + T_{X_0(\omega)}(\theta_1\omega) } = (\theta_1\omega){T{X_0(\omega)}(\theta_1 \omega)}  = X_{T_{X_0(\omega)}(\theta_1\omega)}(\theta_1\omega)$ and the last one is equal to $ X_{T_x} \circ \theta_1$ under $P_x$, so the setence before the last one should read $X_{\tau}(\omega) = X_{T_x{\theta_1\omega}}(\theta_1\omega)$ am I correct? Btw, thank you a lot!

Yes, good catch! Now fixed.
